# Decrypt Windows Credential Files

Tags: c#, c++, delphi, winapi

I'm into a project that need to manage (write/read) cached credentials. In my case, specially (TERMSRV) or popular known as remote desktop.

On my Windows 7, I already discovered that the files are stored in "AppData\Local\Microsoft\Credentials". When I open mstsc (remote desktop client), and save a credential, a new file (occult and protected by the system) is created on this dir. I tried to open the file on notepad, and it's encrypted data. For what I saw, looks like Windows use Data Protection API(DPAPI), specifically [CryptProtectData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261(v=vs.85).aspx)/[CryptUnprotectData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380882(v=vs.85).aspx) functions, to save/retrieve the cached credentials.

My first try, was on [CredRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374804(v=vs.85).aspx) function, but I discovered that domain passwords ([CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_PASSWORD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374788(v=vs.85).aspx) - exactly the type for terminal services), can only be read by authentication packages. After this discover, I started searching for some tools, and I found that some people is injecting a DLL into LSASS process, to do the job. But I saw [Nirsoft NetPass](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html) that successfully decrypt my saved passwords, and through Process Explorer, I didn't saw any new DLL injected on LSASS. Looks like he works directly on the credential file using CryptUnprotectData.

The question is: is there anyway to retrieve the cached passwords, from this file, without the need to inject dll and do this kind of stuff? If yes, the way would be CryptUnprotectData? Finally, if yes, what is that DATA_BLOB the function receives? The content of the file? I just can't understand how to use that function, from where I take the blob?

**Edit::**

I posted this question on Windows/WinAPI tags only, but almost no views and no answers. I believe the main question, is language independent, but I'm doing the project in Delphi, so here goes the Delphi code for CredRead, that gets only username, but can't list password, because the account is domain type (CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_PASSWORD)

```
type
 PCREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTEW = ^_CREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTEW;
  _CREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTEW = record
    Keyword: LPWSTR;
    Flags: DWORD;
    ValueSize: DWORD;
    Value: LPBYTE;
  end;


  PCREDENTIALW = ^_CREDENTIALW;
  _CREDENTIALW = record
    Flags: DWORD;
    Type_: DWORD;
    TargetName: LPWSTR;
    Comment: LPWSTR;
    LastWritten: FILETIME;
    CredentialBlobSize: DWORD;
    CredentialBlob: LPBYTE;
    Persist: DWORD;
    AttributeCount: DWORD;
    Attributes: PCREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTEW;
    TargetAlias: LPWSTR;
    UserName: LPWSTR;
  end;

PCredentialArray = array of PCREDENTIALW;

const
  CRED_TYPE_GENERIC                 = 1;
  CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_PASSWORD         = 2;
  CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_CERTIFICATE      = 3;
  CRED_TYPE_DOMAIN_VISIBLE_PASSWORD = 4;
  CRED_TYPE_MAXIMUM                 = 5;  // Maximum supported cred type
  CRED_TYPE_MAXIMUM_EX              = CRED_TYPE_MAXIMUM + 1000;  // Allow new applications to run on old OSes

var
  Form1: TForm1;

function CredReadW(TargetName: LPCWSTR; Type_: DWORD; Flags: DWORD; var Credential: PCREDENTIALW): BOOL; stdcall; external 'advapi32.dll';
function CredEnumerateW(Filter: LPCWSTR; Flags: DWORD; out Count: DWORD; out Credential: PCredentialArray): BOOL; stdcall; external 'advapi32.dll';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Credentials: PCredentialArray;
  Credential: PCREDENTIALW;
  UserName: WideString;
  i: integer;
  dwCount: DWORD;
begin
    if CredEnumerateW(PChar('TERM*'), 0, dwCount, Credentials) then
    begin
      for i:= 0 to dwCount - 1  do
        begin
            if CredReadW(Credentials[i].TargetName, Credentials[i].Type_, 0, Credential) then
            begin
              UserName:= Credential.UserName;
              Memo1.Lines.Add(Credentials[i].TargetName + ' :: ' + UserName + ' >> ' + IntToStr(Credentials[i].Type_));
              Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Credential.CredentialBlobSize));
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C++/C#?

Comment: On WinAPI no one knows the answer. The question is language independent, it's a question about windows function, you can answer and paste your C++/C# code here (if you have some), and if this clear the problem, I'll accept the answer. The code in Delphi is just one snippet to people have one idea about what I tried.

Comment: What is your endgoal, login to terminal services with the cached credential or mimic the functionality in Netpass? PS: your code leaks memory, you need to free the buffer returned by CreadReadW via the means of `CredFree`.

Comment: My first goal is to mimic functionality to be able to read/write credentials, including existing ones, already created. And yes, the CredFree is necessary, I just didn't it because I saw the code isn't working, so I just dont know if I should continue in this way (CredRead) or try something else...

Comment: you will have to do both (CredEnumerate/CreadRead) and decrypt the files for recovering the passwords...

Comment: The decryption of the files is done via CryptUnprotectData, right? So what I do is something like: read the file as bytes, and pass this bytes to CryptUnprotectData?